# WebGL is not initializing properly?

Tags: 11.04, firefox, google-chrome, webgl

I've the latest stable versions of firefox and chrome. But when I run [bodybrowser](http://bodybrowser.googlelabs.com/) I get the following error:

> Google Body uses WebGL, a new standard
>   for 3D on the Web. Your browser
>   supports WebGL, but WebGL is not
>   initializing properly

How can I get this to work?

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by [selecting the best answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 2):

In order to check whether your browser supports WebGL, visit
http://get.webgl.org/

Linux and WebGL have teething problems, and in many cases it just does not work.
Whenever there is a support question, you need to provide

1. what graphics card you have
2. which driver you are using (mostly if they are the free/closed ones for ATI or NVidia). Newer Intel graphics drivers may be supported, older are quite unlikely.

In most cases you can force your browser to use WebGL; follow the link that it given when you visit http://get.webgl.org/

Comment: @user4124- I tried this - webgl.disabled false webgl.force-enabled true webgl.force_osmesa false webgl.prefer-native-gl false webgl.shader_validator true webgl.verbose true -- didnt work     then I tried this - To Enable WebGL:

1. Type about:config in your browser

2. Mouse Right-Click

3. Choose New - Boolean

4. Type in new appeared window: webgl.enabled_for_all_sites

   Enable = True

5. Restart Firefox.....     didnt work either!!!!

Answer (score 1):

In Chromium (or Google Chrome) you can type `about:flags` and search (ctrl + f) to WebGL. Activate it then restart your browser.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for the WebGL support to become broken by a misbehaving WebGL app.  When this happens, WebGL apps will not be able to run.

This can be fixed by restarting all instances of your browser.

A relatively non-destructive way of doing this in Chromium (so you don't lose open pages) is to go to `about:flags` and disable WebGL (by selecting 'Enable'), then 'Relaunch Now', then re-enable WebGL and relaunch again.

There's probably a more straightforward way, but I am not aware of it.